# Protractor finding ng-repeat elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I have an `ng-repeat` with the syntax of

```
    ng-repeat="(occupancy_category, singleCardCategoryData) in categoryCardServiceResponse | orderBy: 'occupancy_category'"
```

I want to use `protractor` to write a test and count the cards but for some reason it can't find it. That is what I assume the error `"Expected 0 to be 6"` means. Here is my it block for the test

```
  it('should check number of category status cards', function(){
     var categoryCards = element.all(by.repeater('(occupancy_category, singleCardCategoryData) in categoryCardServiceResponse | orderBy: occupancy_category'));

     expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:8000/app/#/dashboard');
     expect(categoryCards.count()).toBe(6)
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing this part from the test will work

```
orderBy: occupancy_category
```

So the new code would look like

```
var categoryCards = element.all(by.repeater('(occupancy_category, singleCardCategoryData) in categoryCardServiceResponse'));
```